# Like query is locking the table?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column I'm doing a like '%X%' query on, I did it this way for simplicity with the knowledge that I'd have to revisit it as the amount of data grew.

However, one thing I did not expect was for it to lock the table, but it appears to be doing so.  The query is slow, and if the query is running, other queries will not finish until it's done.

What I'm asking for are some general ideas as to why this might be happening, and advice on how I can drill down into SQL Server to get a better feel for exactly what's going on with respect to the locks.

I should mention that all of the queries are SELECT except for a service I have waking every 60 seconds to check for various things and potentially INSERT rows.  This table is never updated, CRD only, not CRUD, but the issue is consistent rather than intermittent.

Comment: If it can't use an index then it has to do a table scan and these generally lock - at least after escalation which will happen quite soon! - the table to avoid "dirty reads" and other such phenomena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because LIKE '%X%' will force a complete scan. If there is an index that it can use, then the engine will scan the index, but it will need to read every row. If there is no nonclustered index, then the engine will perform a clustered index scan, or a table scan if the table is a heap.

This happens because of the LIKE %somevalue% construction. If you had a phonebook, say, and you were asked to find everyone with an X somewhere in the middle of their name, you'd have to read every entry in the index. If, on the other hand, it was LIKE 'X%', you'd know you only had to look at the entries beginning with 'X'.

Since it has to scan the entire table, it is likely to escalate the rowlocks to a table lock - this is not a flaw, SQL Server is almost always right when it determines that it would be more efficient for it to place a single lock on the table than 100,000 row locks, but it does block  write operations.

My suggestion is that you try to find a better query than one involving LIKE '%X%'.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was something faulty with SQL Server, I just didn't understand why it would be doing that.  If I'm understanding you correctly, it will lock the table for efficiency reasons, even if there are no incoming inserts, and so forth?  Where can I get more information regarding lock escalation, what causes it, and so forth?  The surprising info to me is that a shared lock wasn't enough.

Comment: Sometimes developers think that this sort of behaviour must be a flaw in the RDBMS. :) So I was being defensive in advance. Anyway, with the exception of read operations under READ UNCOMMITTED, locks are always placed, and even under RU, a few locks are taken. The issue isn't the placing of the locks, it is the duration and scope. If you can make the read more efficient (by using criteria such that SQL Server doesn't have to read every row) then you will dramatically reduce the scope and duration of the block.

Comment: Ok, your answer was helpful.  I've done some googling and came across a few articles explaining the behavior better for me.  I would not have expected such lock escalation, but after reading up on it, I understand why it does it now.  I always knew that query would be revisited, I just didn't expect it to be revisited so soon :)